# Change cache settings programmatically in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a block which displays list of RSS feed from an external site. I want to keep caching other blocks except the mentioned block. Howto do that?

For example, I have *blockA*, *blockB* and *blockC*. I only want to change the *blockB*'s cache settings permamently to `DRUPAL_NO_CACHE` and leave other blocks as they are and I want to do that programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the caching roles in the specific module that creates youre block.
In the block info like beneath:

```
function pref_block_info() {
  return array(
    'pref_main' => array(
      'info' => t('Display flash game for auth. users'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    ),
    'pref_winner' => array(
      'info' => t('Show the winner of the last week.'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    ),
    'pref_leader' => array(
      'info' => t('Show the leader of the current week.'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    ),
    'pref_top' => array(
      'info' => t('Show the top 10 of the current week.'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by Jurgo is perfectly right, if you are defining the block within your own module.

In case if you want to change the caching behavior of a block written by some other module then you can use the function `mymodule_block_list_alter`

```
function mymodule_block_list_alter(&$blocks, $theme, $code_blocks) {
  // Remove the caching on rss feeds block. 
  // Here rss-feeds is the unique key for the block
  $blocks['rss-feeds']['cache'] = DRUPAL_NO_CACHE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will reduce the work by going to performance settings page (*admin/settings/performance*) & clicking *"cleared cached data"* by scrolling down.

But make sure that this page is only accessed by administrator.

For *Drupal 7* is same as *Drupal 6*:

```
<?php
  drupal_flush_all_caches();
  drupal_set_message('cache flushed.');
?>
```

Comment: i am sorry for being so ununderstandable

Answer (score 1):

Where do the blocks come from? That's important. As Jurgo said, you can specify it in `hook_block_info` if it's a custom module. If they are views blocks, there is a caching setting per display within views that handles this. If they are blocks provided by some other module, you'd need to directly query the database to change the block's caching setting.

As a general note, to display RSS feeds, just use Feeds and Views. Then you don't write custom code at all for any of this.